# Wmplib.WindowsMediaPlayer, pause() function doesn't work on c#

Tags: c#, wmplib

I am currently working with `WmpLib.WindowsMediaPlayer ()` but when I click on play after clicking pause the music starts again at the beginning instead of continuing and I do not understand why.

Could someone explain to me?

```
private void play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        player.URL = SoundFilePath;
        player.controls.play();
    }


private void pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       player.controls.pause();
   }
```

Comment: It starts back at the start of the song because the code creates a complete new instance of WMP *and* assigns the URL again.  Don't do that, you need to know to skip these things when you click Play again. Use a variable named, say, *Paused" and set it to true in your Pause event handler.  Only ever create the WindowsMediaPlayer once, it is an expensive mother, consider the constructor of your form.

Comment: I've created new instance before play() function but no positive response.